# How can I trace all items of a nested array?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have an array like this:

```
$arr = array(
             0 => array (0 => null, 1=> 'something1'),
             1 => array (0 => null, 1=> null, 2 => 'something2'),
             2 => null
            );
```

I need to unset all item which have `null` value. So this is expected result:

```
$arr = array(
             0 => array (1=> 'something1'),
             1 => array (2 => 'something2'),
            );
```

How can I do that?

---

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
function trace_arr(&$arr){
    foreach($arr as $item){
        if ( $item == null ) { 
            unset($item);
        } 
    }
}

array_walk($arr, 'trace_arr');
```

Comment: Did you know `array_filter()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a recursive array filter function:

```
<?php  
$arr = array(
             0 => array (0 => null, 1=> 'something1'),
             1 => array (0 => null, 1=> null, 2 => 'something2'),
             2 => null
            );

function array_filter_recursive(&$array,$callback=null){
    $array = array_filter($array,$callback);
    foreach($array as &$v){
        if(is_array($v)){
           array_filter_recursive($v,$callback);
        }        
    }
}
array_filter_recursive($arr,function($a){ return !is_null($a);});
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

try this PHP code:

```
function remove_null_values(&$array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            remove_null_values($array[$key]);
        }
        elseif($value === null) unset($array[$key]); 
    }
}

remove_null_values($arr);
```

Comment: @Micea Soaica , that's a good advanced function , good job - up vote.

Answer (score 1):

if you working with **stable array** you can use `array_filter()`

**basic Example** :

```
 foreach ($arr as $newarray ) {
       if (is_array($newarray)) 
          print_r( array_filter($newarray) ); 
          }
```

**Result** :

> Array
>   (
>       [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42761852/7465452) => something1
>   )
>   Array
>   (
>       [2] => something2
>   )

unless you work with Databases or including data from **Unstable** files or sources and you want (full checkout function) then see @Mircea comment : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42761852/7465452)

Comment: I'm wonder, why this answer earned 4 upvotes? It doesn't work. Can you please give me a fiddle of it?!

Comment: This is not only removing real `NULL` values and you not create a new/filtered array , you just dump stuff. And what if your `array_filter()` gets an non-array value?! Really simple, but very unsafe. But the formating in you answer seems ok :-)

Comment: @stack , The simplest answer are favor to the general public

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions , on his question he mention what he want  with  " expected result: " and he follow it with : 
`$arr = array(
             0 => array (1=> 'something1'),
             1 => array (2 => 'something2'),
            );` , so the exact result was built based on that example .

Comment: i mention "if you working with stable array" read before spam . end of story. case closed

Answer (score 0):

an alternative implementation to accomplish this :

```
$array = array(
    0 => array (0 => null, 1=> 'something1'),
    1 => array (0 => null, 1=> null, 2 => 'something2', 3 => array(0 => null, 1 => 'f')),
    2 => null
);


function filterNulls($array, &$list = []) {
    array_walk($array, function ($value, $key) use (&$list) {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            if (!empty($value)) {
                $list[$key] = $value;
            }
        } else {
            $list[$key] = filterNulls($value);
        }
    });

    return $list;
}

print_r(filterNulls($array));
```

live sample: https://3v4l.org/IDdYD